# Why is the result of a generic mapped type not equally to an union type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(readonly id: number, readonly value: string) {}
}

class Bar {
    constructor(readonly id: number, readonly value: string, readonly name: string) {}
}

interface Store {
    foo: Foo;
    bar: Bar;
}
```

The following function will not infer a union type from the mapped type of the Store.

```
const foo1 = <K extends keyof Store, E extends Store[K]>() => {
    let result: E = undefined!;
    result = new Bar(1, 'some-value', 'some-name') // Type 'Bar' is not assignable to type 'E'
};
```

However:

```
const foo2 = () => {
    let result: Foo | Bar = undefined!;
    result = new Bar(1, 'some-value', 'some-name'); // Ok
};
```

Compiles fine.

Why is this happening, and is there an alternative approach? :)

Comment: Consider `foo1<'foo', Foo>();`. In that case you're putting a `Bar` into a variable of type `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said, you're returning either `Foo` or `Bar`from this function, but the function itself cannot return `E` because it doesn't know what `K` is at compile time.

```
const foo1 = <K extends keyof Store, E extends Store[K]>() => {
    let result: Store[K];
    result = new Bar(1, 'some-value', 'some-name') // works
};
```

Instead return `Store[K]`, which is basically `Foo | Bar`